# How to upload pdf from url string to dropbox in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, nsdata, dropbox-api

I've been facing a problem to upload pdf from url using dropbox Api ,I've permission of Api for **Datastores** 
Here is my Code,

```
 //App Delegate
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary   *)launchOptions
  {
     DBSession *dbSession = [[DBSession alloc]
                        initWithAppKey:APP_KEY appSecret:APP_SECRET
                        root:kDBRootDropbox]; // either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
    [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];

  }
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {
  if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
        // At this point you can start making API calls
    }
    return YES;
 }

return NO;
}
```

My ViewController

```
 //DropboxController.m   

 self.restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
    self.restClient.delegate = self;
      if (![[DBSession sharedSession]isLinked])
        {
            [[DBSession sharedSession]linkFromController:self];
        }

      NSString *str=[urlStrin stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    _pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:targetURL];
   NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
                                                                  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
                                                                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
                                                                  ]];

    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DemoReport.pdf"];
    [_pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    [self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];
    // Upload file to Dropbox
    NSString *destDir = @"/";

    [self.restClient uploadFile:filePath toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:resourceDocPath];
```

**EDITED** I'm following this [this dropbox tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios)
I can just create simple text file easily but I'm not able to upload pdf from url to dropbox ,Please help me out,sorry for my bad English

Comment: Datastore permissions will *not* allow you to do any operations on files, but if you are successfully uploading a text file, then you must have used the right permissions. Could you tell us what error you're getting and when?

Comment: @smarx thanks man.. Now I'm able to upload document but with iphone path /Users/mymac/Dropbox/var/mobile/Applications/164245D9-0DB6-439C-8838-9FA612362F08/Documents document folder and facing to upload my pdf to my custom folder. I want to upload document at /Users/mymac/Dropbox/myfolder ,Could you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can upload the file from wherever the file is stored.

Comment: @smarx I can upload my document with my full iphone path like /var/mobile/Applications/164245D9-0DB6-439C-8838-9FA612362F0‌​8/Documents  ,I don't want all those extra folder Sir I need to upload my file like  Dropbox/myfolder to my custom folder